# Contract management with customizable HTML export

Tags: html, api, legal, contract-manager

I'm looking for a contract management tool that allows customizable HTML export. In addition to your typical contract management features, we'd like to be able to write a set of rules for a specific contract that allows us to export the entire contract in custom HTML. Three examples of what I mean below.

It'd be ideal if the entire contract can be exported, per my custom rules, into one giant HTML document or even just an HTML fragment. In addition, some other features I'd love to have include:

- An API to export/get the HTML-formatted output of the contract
- An on-premise solution

Are there any tools or systems that can do this? Or combinations of systems?

Finally, the reason we are looking at this is because we have a lot of legal documents that we want to display on our website for customers. There is a disconnect between the HTML version of a webpage and the legal version of a contract.

Thank you!

---

#### Example 1

Wrap all *Heading 1* paragraphs in `<h2 id="section_num">` tags, where `section_num` is the bullet numbering of the section heading.

MS Word:

> ### 3.5 Procedure in case of death or incompetence

HTML output:

```
<h2 id="3.5">Procedure in case of death or incompetence</h2>
```

---

#### Example 2

Wrap all *Normal* and *No Spacing* paragraphs in `<p>` tags.

MS Word:

> If we are notified of death or incompetence of a Customer or of a restriction being placed on the Customer...

HTML output:

```
<p>If we are notified of death or incompetence of a Customer or of a restriction being placed on the Customer...</p>
```

---

#### Example 3

Convert all bullet lists into the properly formatted bullet list.

MS Word:

> a. Non-operation of the Service for such period as may be decided by the Company per its internal policy
>
> b. Death and incapacity and incompetency of the Customer
>
> c. Providing false or incorrect information

HTML output:

```
<ol type="a">
  <li>Non-operation of the Service for such period as may be decided by the Company per its internal policy</li>
  <li>Death and incapacity and incompetency of the Customer</li>
  <li>Providing false or incorrect information</li>
</ol>
```